# Calculate probability of isolated nodes after removing edges

Tags: probability, graph-theory, trees

Consider a graph with no isolated nodes that follows this structure:

[image]

The graph is a binary tree with additional edges.

How can we calculate the probability that this graph will still have no isolated nodes after removing $k$ random edges?

Comment: What are the additional edges? Are you asking about this specific graph, or any graph?

Comment: The additional edges are the blue ones, and I'm asking for this graph in specific